# CPython as a library for C (To execute Python code from C)

Tags: python, c, compiler-construction, arm, cpython

I'm not C expert so what I'm asking might be crazy.

Is it possible to compile CPython using an ARM c-compiler (like yagarto or arm-gcc)
and then call it from a C application to process lines of python code?

If so, what are the resources/documents I should be looking at?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Embedding Python in Another Application](http://docs.python.org/extending/embedding.html) on Python.org

Comment: So all I have to do is download an ARM compiled version of Python somewhere, drop it in the same dir as the C application and then use it as described on that page... seems simple enough. I had thought it would've been more complex :p I embed it in C# a lot didn't think it would be similar :) thnx!